# Range median query in an array in O(1) time using preprocessing

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, range, time-complexity, median

In classroom we learnt about RMQ to LCA to RMQ problems and how to support the operation range minimum query in O(1) time. As an exercise my professor has assigned me to support the operation : Range median query in O(n) space, O(n) preprocessing time and O(1) select time.

Let's say I have an array A that contains 8, 7, 9, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3. Given median(i, j) we should get the median between the ith and jth elements (inclusive) after sorting the array. A sorted is 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. For example median(2,6) = A[4] = 6 (because median of 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 is 6).

I found other solutions that suggest using segment trees but the complexity is not O(1) in those cases. Is it possible to solve this problem in a similar manner that we solve the RMQ to LCA to RMQ problem?

Comment: What does median mean here? `A[(i + j) / 2]`? How do you resolve the median of an even number of items? `(A[floor((i + j) / 2)] + A[ceil((i + j) / 2)]) / 2`?

Comment: I haven't really slept lately, the array is meant to be sorted before we calculate for the median. If the number of the sub array is even then exactly as you said.

Comment: if the sorting is not included in this problem, my previous comment is O(1)

Comment: I can't use normal sorting as the lower bound for sorting is O(nlogn). I need to use a preprocessing method that takes O(n) time as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with comparisons. If it were, you could comparison sort N elements in O(N) time by preprocessing the input and computing median(i, i) for each i from 0 to N-1.

You probably misunderstood the task you were assigned - you were probably supposed to compute medians for subarrays of the *original* array, not of a sorted version of the array.

Comment: I think he meant that median(i,j) returns the median of the sub array A[i,...,j] which is possible since median(i,i) would just return A[i], the reason I think he meant that is that range minimum query (the same rmq he's talking about) return the minimum in the sub array not in the sorted array, so range median query should be the median of the non sorted sub array.

Comment: @TomerWolberg: That would make more sense, and it's quite likely what the professor really wanted, but it doesn't match what the actual question says.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use a non-comparative sorting algorithm. Examples I know of being [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) (`O(wn)`, where `w` is the word size) and [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (`O(n+k)`, where `k` is the maximum key value). Both of these are linear with respect to input size.

Then, you could just look up the correct position within the list, which is an `O(1)` operation. Both sorting methods are within your space requirements -- radix sort is `O(n+k)` and counting sort is `O(k)`.